# corrupt C\documents and settings\no name\application data\sun\java\jre1.7.0_67

Tags: windows, windows-xp, java

I am trying to initiate silverlight and have a corrupt file.  Can anyone inform me what to do with this file (fix or delete)?  How would I go about replacing the file so I can download java for starlight? The corrupt file is as follows: C\documents and settings\no name\application data\sun\java\jre1.7.0_67 ?
Thanks, Don